# How to include multiple template id in SXA scope query

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA version 1.8.1. I created a scope item and using that in search.
I need to list all the items of templates A and B under a given location. Is it possible to have a query to include multiple templates?
My query returns result if I have one template, but how do I include multiple templates?

Now my query is something like this

```
location:{E59F0AFE-FE69-4393-9955-23B48D28FB76};+template:{2BE81A84-A619-46A8-B5B4-BEB7D2D7CC40}
```

How can I include one more template id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the extra template Id in the same way as the first. E.g.:

```
location:{a4d6582e-dfb8-4492-95fe-c70b6969cbb9};template:{ad0e07c0-d08d-49df-9cdd-86ac2cd49be4};template:{324733cf-afec-4281-9a18-03b6cfc4e535}
```

But remove the `+` And modifier on the `template` filters and add it to the `location` filters like this:

```
+location:{a4d6582e-dfb8-4492-95fe-c70b6969cbb9};template:{ad0e07c0-d08d-49df-9cdd-86ac2cd49be4};template:{324733cf-afec-4281-9a18-03b6cfc4e535}
```

Doing that makes the `location` a must have and the `template` filters OR's

Comment: Thank you for answer !!